# Take a screenshot in higher resolution than my laptop

Tags: resolution, screenshot

I want to print a map : https://www.geoportail.gouv.fr/carte?c=1.9000735000000002,42.81091681279062&z=13&l0=ORTHOIMAGERY.ORTHOPHOTOS::GEOPORTAIL:OGC:WMTS(1)&l1=GEOGRAPHICALGRIDSYSTEMS.MAPS.SCAN25TOUR.CV::GEOPORTAIL:OGC:WMTS(1)&d2=4367575(1)&d3=4367578(1)&permalink=yes

The problem is I have an old mac book pro 2010, and the full map never fit in my screen for a screenshot. When I try this way, and I print it, the result isn't quite good. I need to see a lot of details.

I tried to take a screenshot from https://screenshot.guru/,  so I can get higher resolution, but you need to make an initial click to remove displayed help, so it doesnt work.

Do you know how I should do it ?

Comment: It's a bitmap, try finding a vector based system. If the data is downloadable, see if it runs in QGIS and do it offline.

Comment: mmm I don't think it can be downloaded... Otherwise, people would do it to print their own maps. This is the only map I need, I cannot use other types of maps like Open Street Maps vector based maps unfortunately

Comment: The UK Ordnance Survey office releases Zoomstack which give you just about everything you need. Many other countries do the same. Perhaps the French should be _persuaded_ to do the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an ever better solution I think here:

https://megamorf.gitlab.io/2022/02/16/take-high-resolution-screenshots-of-websites/

Open chrome or firefox console in responsive mode, and put the resolution you want, here I put 4K = 4096 × 2160 px

It will load the page at this resolution

Then, you can make a screenshot with console :screenshot for firefox

Comment: This looks good. In Chrome, open dev mode with F12 and device toolbar with Ctrl + Shift + M. Set the resolution in the centre of the bar and configure the webpage as you wish. Then use the "Capture screenshot" option in the "More options" menu in the top right of the device toolbar.

Answer (score 1):

I think I could find a way to do it.

I can go to https://pikwy.com/

Select resolution 3840x2160 4K UHD, and png format

Then to remove the help in the picture, you can use the embed url you can find in the share icon.

Warning: This service is free, but it appears to have a limit !

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need screenshot? You can print the image and produce for example PDF with quite a lot of resolution. For me it make it like 3200x1600 map (via print to PDF)

Comment: When I use print icon, I cannot see all my trace in the screen. It would be different if my computer manage higher resolution !

Comment: @JuliatzindelToro, try by changing browser